# How to fix <address>.transfer exception : member transfer not found?

Tags: solidity, truffle, remix

this code is running on version 0.4.24 on remix but not on version 0.5.0+, I also tried to compile it with truffle on Windows 10 which also gives the exception.

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract lottery {

    address public manager;
    address[] public players;

    constructor() public{
        manager = msg.sender;
    }

    modifier restricted(){
        require(msg.sender == manager);
        _;
    }

    function enterLottery() public payable {
        require(msg.value > 0.01 ether);
        players.push(msg.sender);
    }

    function random() public view returns(uint) {
        return uint(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(block.difficulty,now,players)));
    }

    function pickWinner() public restricted{

        uint index = random() % players.length;
        address winner = players[index];
        players = new address[](0);

        winner.transfer(address(this).balance);
    }

    function getPlayers() public view returns(address[] memory){
        return players;
    }  
}
```

`winner.transfer(address(this).balance);` isn't working. I also made the `pickWinner()` payable but that didn't fix the error

Answer (score 2):

Thank God, I found what I was missing.
In solidity 0.5.3:
The address type comes in two flavors, **address** and **address payable**: Same as address, but with the additional members transfer and send.
[enter link description here](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/types.html#address)

create "address payable array of players"
e.g. address payable[] public players;
also change getPlayers() return datatype to address players[]